# Do I still need the Xbox Bluetooth adapter to use multiple Xbox One controllers on Windows 10?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

The new Xbox One controller ([reviewed here](http://www.cnet.com/products/microsoft-xbox-one-wireless-controller-2016/)) is advertised to have Bluetooth support and no additional adapter needed to connect to a Windows 10 PC. However, if I want to pair two of these to a laptop, would I still need the older adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Laptop Bluetooth interface usually supports connection of many BT devices.

According to Microsoft's Xbox [support site](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-xbox-one-controller-to-pc), depending on Windows version you can connect up to 8 controllers with windows